# AsyncTask vs IntentService vs что-то другое при работе с сетью

Tags: java, android, service, android-asynctask

Есть некоторое приложение, которое по запросу пользователя загружает некоторые данные из сети и отображает их. Сетевые запросы в этом приложении выполняются в отдельном потоке средствами `AsyncTask`.

Ввиду того, что многие категорически советуют не использовать `AsyncTask` при работе с интернетом (а выносить сетевые запросы в сервис) и возник данный вопрос.

**Чуть подробнее:**

Суть приложения - отображение списка (текстовых) новостей из нескольких источников.

**Как это реализовано сейчас:**

Есть активити с `Navigation Drawer`, в котором отображается список сайтов, по клику на определенный пункт меню появляется фрагмент, содержащий `RecyclerView`, куда с помощью `AsyncTask` загружаются данные с выбранного сайта.

При прокрутке `RecyclerView` до определенного элемента запускается `AsyncTask` который подгружает в `RecyclerView` следующую порцию информации и так далее (эдакий `Endless RecyclerView`).

При выборе другого пункта меню, появляется другой фрагмент, но с таким же принципом работы (просто данные грузятся из другого источника).

При создании каждого из фрагментов выполняется `setRetainInstance(true)`, то есть при изменении конфигурации устройства данные из `AsyncTask` благополучно вернутся в нужный фрагмент.

Процесс извлечения нужной информации с сайтов организован с помощью `Jsoup`.

**Вопросы:**

Чем плоха такая архитектура данного приложения? (в части использования `AsyncTask` и в общем).

**Хорошим ли тоном для данной конкретной задачи является использование `AsyncTask`? Или же стоит перенести работу с сетью в сервис?** (я понимаю, что не все типы сервисов работают не в главном потоке).

А если все же стоит перенести работу с сетью в сервис, то при необходимости загрузки данных запускать сервис, загружать данные, возвращать данные во фрагмент и завершать сервис? И так каждый раз?

Честно говоря, хоть и на каждом углу написано, что `AsyncTask` - это плохо, я не вижу явных причин для вынесения работы с сетью в сервис в данном конкретном приложении. Но раз многие говорят, значит я чего-то не понимаю. Объясните мне это, пожалуйста.

По сути, `AsyncTask` же предназначен для кратковременных задач, а у меня загружается очень небольшой объем данных (текст), и в итоге `AsyncTask` как раз отрабатывает за пару секунд.

А основное назначение сервиса - это, насколько я понял, выполнение **длительных** фоновых задач.

Еще раз повторюсь - я не утверждаю, что в данном случае лучшим решением будет использование `AsyncTask`, но и аргументов против его использования я не вижу.

А может есть какие-либо другие более правильные архитектурные решения для данной задачи?

Хоть интернет и читал (очень много читал), но буду рад как ссылкам, где описывается что-то подобное (может я пропустил), так и Вашим ответам по данной теме и Вашим мнениям по данному вопросу.

Comment: То что у вас выполняется запрос за 2 секунды не означает что у условного Васи в деревне с плохим интернетом он выполнится так же быстро. Если выбирать между AsyncTask'ом и IntentServis'ом то я бы выбрал сервис. Но у себя в проектах я использую RxJava + Retrofit и очень доволен.

Comment: @temq, Под быстрым выполнением я подразумевал то, что загружаются очень маленькие данные (порядка нескольких килобайт), а не файлы в мегабайтах. Я может чего-то не понимаю, но те сервера, откуда я получаю данные, не являются `RESTful`. Я забираю голый `html`. Насколько я понимаю, `Retrofit` в данном случае не особо хорошее решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Честно говоря, хоть и на каждом углу написано, что AsyncTask - это
>   плохо

Так говорят только те, кто не умеет их готовить. `AsyncTask` вполне нормальная практика, если вы умеете справляться с пограничными кейсами: поворот экрана, уничтожени контекста и т.п.

`AsyncTask` не рекомендуют использовать по большей степени потому что есть уже готовые нормальные библиотеки типо Volley, Retrofit и т.п.

Сервисы используются для тяжёлых задач или же для периодических задач.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, `Retrofit` мне не подходит, так как сервера, откуда я загружаю данные, не предоставляют `REST API`, я просто забираю голый `html`. По поводу `Volley`, `okHTTP` и подобным им библиотекам: **`Jsoup` загружает данные** синхронно и дальше сама же парсит их. Для обеспечения асинхронности я и использую `AsyncTask`. Есть ли смысл тащить за собой библиотеки только лишь для обеспечения асинхронной загрузки данных (а потом передавать полученные данные `jsoup` для разбора)?

Comment: Еще дело в том, что этот проект я хочу показывать в портфолио, и человек, который будет смотреть код, может увидеть `AsyncTask` и сделать нехорошие выводы (хоть и, возможно, использование асинстаска тут вполне уместно).

Comment: Чуть подробнее объясню почему я не хочу тянуть в проект `Volley`/`okHTTP`/etc. `Jsoup` сама **загружает** и сама же **парсит** страницы. Нужно лишь обеспечить асинхронность загрузки. Стоит ли лишь для обеспечения асинхронности тянуть `Volley`/`okHTTP`/etc? В случае их использования, получать `html` я буду ими, а потом отдавать `Jsoup`, но ведь `Jsoup`и сама может загружать данные, правда только синхронно.

Comment: @Burence если вы сделаете всё на `AsyncTask` и корректно обработаете повороты экрана и т.п., то это будет наоборот плюсом в портфолио. Если же вам откажут в приёме на работу из-за использования `AsyncTask`, то лишь будет говорить о слабой компетенции тех, кто вас нанимает.

Answer (score 1):

Для задач асинхронной загрузки данных в отдельном потоке используется класс, наследующий `AsyncTaskLoader<D>` вместо `Loader<D>`. Класс `AsyncTaskLoader<D>` является абстрактным и работает как AsyncTask. На основе этого класса вы можете реализовать абстрактный метод `loadInBackground()`.

Слушатель получает информацию от загрузчика. Для этого менеджер регистрирует слушатель `OnLoadCompleteListener<D>`, который прослушивает события. Когда загрузка закончилась, то вызывается метод `onLoadFinished(Loader<D> loader, D result).`

Чтобы загрузчик начал работать, его надо запустить. Запущенный загрузчик следит за данными, пока его не перезапустят или остановят.

Остановленный загрузчик продолжает мониторить изменения в данных, но не сообщает о них. При необходимости вы можете заново запустить или перезапустить остановленный загрузчик.

При перезапуске загрузчик не должен запускать новую загрузку данных и мониторить изменения. Его задача - освободить лишние данные. Это состояние редко используется, но в некоторых случаях оно нужно.

Ваша задача сводится к созданию собственного загрузчика, реализации метода `loadInBackground()` и переопределении методов `onStartLoading()`, `onStopLoading()`, `onReset()`, `onCanceled()`, `deliverResult(D results)`.

Подробнее [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/loader.php).

Вся беда обычного `AsyncTask` заключается в повороте экрана, в основном.

В случае с `AsyncTaskLoader` по поводу поворота экрана за Вас уже позаботились. Этот класс замечательно вписывается под Вашу задачу, но вообще я бы просто посоветовал на собственном устройстве желательно с 2G\3G (медленным интернетом) подгружать новые данные и часто поворачивать экран, при этом мониторить память на устройстве. Если даже при медленном интернете утечек не будет и\или она будет, но скажем, размером с одну активити - можете оставить Ваш вариант.

Но нужно помнить одну важную строчку из GoF - любой код претерпевает изменения.

И если Вы собираетесь и дальше улучшать функционалом приложение, то в любом случае дойдете до точки, когда элементы списка будут загружать более тяжелую информацию(фотографии, местоположение и тд).

Поэтому смотрите на потенциал, насколько необходимо будет его поддерживать.

Comment: Ключевое различие между `AsyncTask` и `AsyncTaskLoader` заключается в том, что первый может потерять `context`, а второй не привязывается к нему. У меня потери контекста быть не может, так как фрагменты удерживаемые. По поводу загрузки картинок - такого не будет, грузится лишь текст.